# Dynamically adding properties with kivy discouraged – why?

Tags: python, kivy

The class `kivy.event.EventDispatcher` has a method called [`apply_property()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.apply_property) which allows adding a property to a class at runtime.
The docs contain a warning:

> This method is not recommended for common usage because you
>   should declare the properties in your class instead of using this
>   method.

It is not clear to me *why* this usage is discouraged, and declaration in class preferred. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `kivy`, but I think it's pretty much always best practice to let the future readers of your code know what properties they can expect to be on an instance of a class.  The first place the future reader (possibly you) will look for information when they see a reference to something they don't understand is in the constructor.  If the property isn't there, they'll be confused and need to start digging to figure out where it was added which can be frustrating/annoying.

Comment: I find it easier to unit test objects when they have all attrs/properties defined before runtime. It's always a mess to mock away just part of a dynamic object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply_property()` is used to add property to a single class instance but has a side effect of polluting properties of other instances as well. Consider following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<MyButton>:
    on_press: print('np' in self.properties())
''')

class MyButton(Button):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mb1 = MyButton(text="mb1")
        mb2 = MyButton(text="mb2")
        mb1.apply_property(np=NumericProperty(100))

        layout = BoxLayout()
        layout.add_widget(mb1)
        layout.add_widget(mb2)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

As you can see, even though I used `apply_property` on `mb1` instance, `mb2` reports that it has such property as well. This is because properties are added to the class, not the instance. However, only `mb1` has an actual value:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<MyButton>:
    on_press: print(self.np)
''')

class MyButton(Button):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mb1 = MyButton(text="mb1")
        mb2 = MyButton(text="mb2")
        mb1.apply_property(np=NumericProperty(100))

        layout = BoxLayout()
        layout.add_widget(mb1)
        layout.add_widget(mb2)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Trying to get the value of `np` property from `mb2` instance yields an `AttributeError`. A safe alternative:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<MyButton>:
    on_press: print(self.np)
''')

class MyButton(Button):
    np=NumericProperty(100)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mb1 = MyButton(text="mb1")
        mb2 = MyButton(text="mb2")

        layout = BoxLayout()
        layout.add_widget(mb1)
        layout.add_widget(mb2)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Source: [this issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2860).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Nykakin's example, `apply_property` also interferes with inheritance in a way 'regular' class variables don't, which might therefore lead to unexpected behaviour. Here, `MyButton2` is a subclass of `MyButton1` and instances get attributes `pp` and `oo`. While assigning a class variable `oo` in `MyButton1` does not interfere with instances of `MyButton2`, adding a `Property` with `apply_property` to an instance of `MyButton1` suddenly makes `pp` inaccessible in `MyButton2`:

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MyButton1(Button):
    pass
class MyButton2(MyButton1):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pp = 11
        self.oo = 42

bl = Builder.load_string("""BoxLayout:
    MyButton1:
        id: hb01
        text: "MyButton1"
    MyButton2:
        id: hb02
        text: "MyButton2"
""")


def on_press(sender):
    on_press.counter += 1
    print "in on_press:"
    try:
        print "  Now pp == {}".format(sender.pp)
    except:
        print "  no attribute 'pp'"
    prop = sender.property('pp', quiet=True)
    sender.apply_property(pp=NumericProperty(on_press.counter))
    print "  Applying property ... Now it's {}".format(sender.pp)
    try:
        print "  Now oo == {}".format(sender.oo)
    except:
        print "  no attribute 'oo'"
    sender.__class__.oo = on_press.counter + 17
on_press.counter = 0

def on_press2(sender):
    print "on_press2:"
    try:
        print "  Now pp == {}".format(sender.pp)
    except:
        print "  no attribute 'pp'"
    try:
        print "  Now oo == {}".format(sender.oo)
    except:
        print "  no attribute 'oo'"

class T01App(App):
    def build(self):
        return bl
    def on_start(self):
        self.root.ids.hb01.bind(on_press=on_press)
        self.root.ids.hb02.bind(on_press=on_press2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    T01App().run()
```